# load nicescroll before html loads default browser scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, nicescroll

I'm using a very useful scrollbar plugin, called [nicescroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll).

This plugin takes some time to load, since I'm already using a lot of jquery in my project.

Is it possible someway to hide the default scroll bar of the browser until the script loads, and then the script would do its job and the new scrollbar would appear?

I'm using this code to initialize the plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nice = $('html').niceScroll({
        cursorborder: "",
        cursorcolor: "#333333",
        cursorwidth: "12px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// Hide Overflow of Body on DOM Ready //
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});

// Show Overflow of Body when Everything has Loaded //
$(window).load(function(){
    $("body").css("overflow", "auto");        
    var nice=$('html').niceScroll({cursorborder:"",cursorcolor:"#333333",cursorwidth:"12px"});
});
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yjyUu/)**

I hope this helps!

Comment: hi thanks for the help but i am not using a container, its the "body" scrollbar i am taking about , how to hide that at first and load it when script loads

Comment: @SakshiSharma Scratch my previous comment; take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a better option to add directly on your CSS.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And then in jQuery:

```
$( function() {
    // activate niceScroll
});
```